# SQL Server - View name in definition is different from actual view name

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I ran into a weird issue in SQL server. I have a view in db named "SPH_F2V_VEB_FIN-04-GLA-07 - Reversed and Cancelled GL Postings", But when ran the following query, I got a definition with the name changed.

```
SELECT object_definition (OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.SPH_F2V_VEB_FIN-04-GLA-07 - Reversed and Cancelled GL Postings'))
```

**Output:**

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[SPH_F2V_VEB_FIN-04-GLA-07 - Reversed & Cancelled GL Postings] AS

SELECT 
    --GL1.[Business Unit],
    GL1.[Company Code],
    GL1.Description,
....
```

If you notice, the name changed to "SPH_F2V_VEB_FIN-04-GLA-07 - Reversed & Cancelled GL Postings", changing **"and"** to **"&"**. At first It seemed like a sql conversion issue or something related to **"and"**, but I tried several views with **"and"** and **"&"**, they seemed to be working as expected.

So, any chance how this could happen ? I am even quite skeptical of how DB allows this. Any idea would be deeply appreciated !!

Comment: @GordonLinoff - I checked the db, the view with '&' is not there. So it's just one view.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can happen if you use [`sp_rename`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-rename-transact-sql) to rename the view.

It is best to drop and create it to rename it.

> Renaming a stored procedure, function, view, or trigger will not
>   change the name of the corresponding object name in the definition
>   column of the sys.sql_modules catalog view. Therefore, we recommend
>   that sp_rename not be used to rename these object types. Instead, drop
>   and re-create the object with its new name.

Comment: You are right. So, they say, **The warning comes after the spells**